# Why does Create() call Select query in golang GORM?

Tags: go-gorm

I just found out whenever I call `db.Create()`, there will be two sql queries called: `insert` and `select`. Especially, the select query:

```sql
SELECT "num", "my_text", "my_int" FROM "product"  WHERE (id = 2)
```

(1) Why does it call select query? Without it, the performance should be even better.

(2) Why select these three columns? There are 18 columns in this table. I don't find any common relationships between the three columns. They are all different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out why. Please correct me if I am wrong.

For example, when I do `db.Create(&product)`,

(1) GORM will load fields’ values, which it doesn't know, from the database to the variable `product`.

(2) The reason why it only selects the three fields is because I don't provide those values in the original `product` variable and GORM doesn't know what those values will be, thus select those fields and then assign them to `product`. For instance, `num` is an auto incremented serial.

(3) If I provide all fields' values to `product` before creating the row, GORM will not call `select` after the `insert`.

---

Btw, GORM is not very smart on this because `my_text` has a default value in the definition such as

```
MyText string `gorm:"default:'abc'"`
```

Thus, even if I don't specify the field, GORM should know what `my_text` value is and no need to select it anymore. But whatever, this may just how GORM designs for now.